# How to position elevateZoom lens

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using elevateZoom for having a lens in some image.

The lens is always centered at the cursor. I do not want it to be this way, I want to cursor to be at the corner of the lens. How can I achieve this?

Here is my code, it is not doing what i want to:

```
function initializeActiveLen(){
  $('#planos .item.active img').elevateZoom({
        zoomType   : "lens",
        lensShape : "round",
        lensSize    : 250,
        zoomWindowPosition: 1,
        zoomWindowOffsetx: 200,
        zoomWindowOffsety: 200,
        containLensZoom: true
  });
}
```

Comment: I think you'd need to change how the plugin works. It doesn't seem possible from what I see in their website.

Comment: @LucasPottersky So what are `zoomWindowOffsetx` and `zoomWindowOffsety` for? I don't get it.

Comment: It is to position the window of the zoomed image. "Positioning the window can be done in by setting a default position, and then using x and y offset to adjust..." http://www.elevateweb.co.uk/image-zoom/examples

Comment: @LucasPottersky `the window of the zoomed image` does not mean the lens?

Comment: See what I mean: http://imgur.com/R95klJv

Comment: @LucasPottersky Ohh ok, thank you man I understand now.